# Mocking Puppeteer Network Requests in SUT

Tags: node.js, jestjs, puppeteer, nock

Does anyone know how to mock network requests that Puppeteer makes when it is used as part of the system under test (but NOT to run the test)?  For example, the system under test uses puppeteer to fetch a URL and return some information about the page.  The test is run using Jest.  I normally use `nock` for this but it seems that they aren't used by Puppeteer's network code.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an answer, but I can confirm that Nock will not work in this case. It can only do its thing if it's running in the same Node processes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
page.setRequestInterception(true);
page.on('request),req =>{
req.respond(data);
})
```

Comment: Wouldn't this require modifying the system under test?

Comment: @StevenMusumeche yes little bit but the tests will be more flexible to use.

Answer (score 1):

I would put a proxy between your SUT and your test runner. I *tried* to use [BrowserMob Proxy](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy) in the past but eventually found an alternative solution (definitely not applicable in your case) so I can't really help with this.

It may be worth trying to give it a shot:

> BrowserMob Proxy allows you to manipulate HTTP requests and responses, capture HTTP content, and export performance data as a HAR file. BMP works well as a standalone proxy server, but it is especially useful when embedded in Selenium tests.